# How to initialize a BigDecimal with a very precise floating point value

Tags: java

I have a database column with Decimal(19,5) size, I want a BigDecimal in java to store the value but if I write

```
 BigDecimal(999999999999999.9999);
```

the value is rounded to 1+E15 which I don't want it to be,So how can I get the complete precision of the number.

One way I know is using

```
BigDecimal("999999999999999.9999");
```

I thought there should be a better option to specify the precision.

Comment: Given that you know the way off. Now why do you think it's not a better option? Do you have any specific issue with that?

Comment: 999999999999999.9999 is not exactly representable in `double`, so that will not work.

Comment: No issue as such,but all I get are numeric values so I don't want to convert them to string,aren't there any other ways to do it?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sorry I didn't get you, how should it be specified?

Comment: @pavi: `999999999999999.9999` in Java is a literal of type `double`.  But `double` cannot exactly represent that value; it's rounded.  So you cannot use a `double` to specify that value as an initializer for `BigDecimal`.

Comment: "I have a database column with Decimal(19,5) size, I want a BigDecimal in java to store the value." I do not understand. You can get the database column directly as a BigDecimal via ResultSet.getBigDecimal(), and you can set it via ResultSet.setBigDecimal(). Where are these double values coming from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a constructor that takes a `String` because the value of `double` constant is rounded by the compiler well before it gets to the `BigDecimal`'s constructor. In other words, the compiler sees your `999999999999999.9999` constant, and converts it to `double`. The `double` type does not have enough precision to store all the nines, so the value gets rounded to `1+E15`, and that's the value that gets passed to `BigDecimal`'s constructor. The precision is gone before the program gets to execute its first instruction.

On the other hand, when you pass a string, you let `BigDecimal` do the interpretation of the sequence of nines, making sure that you get the exact precision that you need.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason that you have to use `BigDecimal` here is that the value will not fit into the double type. The double value will get rounded when passed into the constructor of `BigDecimal`, so no matter what you do you can not recover the original value, if you pass just a double. So you have no better option - use `BigDecimal` like you do.